# Como atribuir um nome de coluna dinamicamente a uma query utilizando o PHP PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou tentando criar uma `update` *query*, de modo a definir o nome da coluna a ser atualizada dinamicamente, mas por alguma razão não consigo fazer isso.

Por quê? E como posso fazer isso?

Meu código atual:

```
//atualizando ideal
public function inserirIdeal() {
    $teste = $this->coluna->__get('coluna');

    $query = 'update tb_lista set ? = ? where item = ?';
    $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $this->coluna->__get('coluna'));
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $this->ideal->__get('ideal'));  
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $this->item->__get('item'));    

    return  $stmt->execute();
}
```

[image: Ilustração do problema em código]

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal como não consegui retorno aqui encontrei o porque não estava conseguindo e gostaria de compartilhar a resposta, pelo que entendi o recomendado é que você coloque o nome da coluna, pois, nomes de tabelas e colunas NÃO PODEM ser substituídos por parâmetros no PDO. E por isso, quando eu coloco em hardcode ele funciona.

Para tornar isso dinâmico, como eu queria, precisa colocar uma condição if, verificar que valor vem naquela variável, e a depender do valor, você chama o método que corresponde aquela determinada coluna.